# How to fetch the data from database and represent in a proper way using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database structure :

```
WORK | NAME | USER_ID
  5  | UL7  |  7
  5  | LL5  |  7
  6  | UR9  |  7
  6  | UL7  |  7
```

i have wrote a function to fetch the data from db which is :

```
function fetchRegion($user_id){
  global $mysqli;
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name,work from region WHERE user_id =?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($work,$name);
  while($stmt->fetch()){
  $row[] = array('work'=>$work,'name'=>$name);
  }
  $stmt->close();
  return $row;
  }
```

Now the problem what i am facing is i want to represent the data as it should display

> 5 => UL7,LL5 and 6 =>UR9,UL7

But i am getting an output in an array. Now what can be done to represent the data to display in the above format rather in an array.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: take note of the "work" value in the first array item. Print the work value and the `=>`.Start a loop of the array. Print the "name" value once in each loop until you discover that the "work" value has changed. At that time print the new work value and another `=>`, and then continue as above. There's nothing tricky or unusual about the code, you just have to break down the task into logical steps and work out all the actions you need to take. Actually implementing those actions is relatively straightforward code. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: @ADyson Can i get any code snippet. I am quite confused

Comment: what exactly is confusing you? Take my description one step at a time and try to implement each bit. If you get stuck on a specific part then explain precisely what it is that's the problem.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("s",     $id suhuld $id not be -->  $user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function along with `GROUP BY` in your sql query like this:

```
SELECT `work`, GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) FROM `region` WHERE `user_id` =? GROUP BY  `name`
```

Then, the fetched results would be like this:

```
work | name
------------
5 | UL7,LL5 
6 | UR9,UL7
```

Hope it helps!